# How to Sort RecyclerView in ascending order according?

Tags: android

> I am getting the distance between two locations and showing it to the recycler view, this is the screenshot :

[image]

> I tried to sort the recyclerView in ascending order(shortest distance first) , but it doesnt work. This is my code :

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
  Collections.sort(partnerModelList, new Comparator<PartnerModel>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(PartnerModel lhs, PartnerModel rhs) {
                    return  String.valueOf(km).substring(0, 5) .compareTo(String.valueOf(km).substring(0, 5));

                }
            });
            notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

> How to achieve this, please let me know . Thanks in millions

Comment: You need to sort your data first in the data source list (the list that provides data for the recyclerview adapter). Once you sort it in the list the adapter will display the data according to your assortion. But you are trying to sort the data after recyclerview adapter starts to bind the data to its viewholder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you are doing is sorting the data 'at a later stage' ie. when the data is being bound to its view holder. What you must do is first sort the data according to the requirements and then bind it to the view holder. preprocessing of data  must ideally be done before it is passed to an adapter, but you could also do these operations in the adapter constructor or any other function that is called before `onbindViewHolder` method of the adapter, and then notify the adapter by calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` or `notifyItemChanged()`

Answer (score 0):

You should do sorting in data like this:

```
...
list.sort()
yourRecyclerViewAdapter.setList(list)
...
```